# Java iterating collection throws ConcurrentModificationException after Save

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using Hibernate for saving the objects to DB. I have a Parent object and set of child objects under it. While iterating over the child objects, if a specific criteria is matched then I publish an event using ApplicationEventPublisher, this event is handled separately, which adds few additional logics and saves the object. After the control returns from event handler, it throws `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

Below is the code:

```
  parent.getChild().forEach(child -> {
    if (child.getStatus().equals("PENDING")) {
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new NewEvent(child));
        publishLifeCycleEvent(deal);
      }
    }
  });
```

There is a Event Listener:

```
  @EventListener
  public void saveChildEvent(NewEvent childEvent) {
    Child child = childEvent.getChild();
    //...do processing
    childRepository.save(child);
  }
```

But it throws java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at this point. How can I rectify this?

```
Stack Trace -
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1493)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1516)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:893)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: SInce you are doing this while iterating over the `child` collection of `parent` it's very likely that `childRepository.save(child)` is changing that collection. WIthout the stacktrace and maybe more core it's hard to tell though. What you could do: a) create a copy of the `child` collection and iterate over that of b) collect the events into a collection while iterating over `child` and publish them in a separate look (or provide a `publishEvents(Collection<NewEvent>)` method which you feed the collection of events to).

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a copy of the list like this:

```
var children = new ArrayList<>(parent.getChild());
children .forEach(child -> {
  if (child.getStatus().equals("PENDING")) {
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new NewEvent(child));
    publishLifeCycleEvent(deal);
  }
});
```